# In Django, how do I print out only the error, but not the key?

Tags: python, html, css, django

```
{{ docform.errors }}


__all__
Please type in the location of this submission.
title
Please write more in Title.
```

When I pass a form to the template and do the above..it prints out everything.

But I don't want the **all** or "title".
I just want the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

```
   {% for f in docform %}
        {{ f.errors }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ docform.non_field_errors }}
```